# Animation in Racket

Tags: racket

[Running program window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn7QX.png) So I'm doing this exercise from pictured programs and I've got the program to do as the exercise wants, but the image in the interaction window looks like a bunch of stacked backgrounds. I'm missing  something with this program and I don't know what it is. [Interaction window after program runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRfrx.png)

Also I might add that this must be done without conditionals, for loops  etc... advanced functions.

You can see that it overlays a white background that keeps the program from populating that space and I can't seem to find a way around this. I've literally brute forced every possible combination that I can think of and this is the best I could come with at this moment.

Exercise explanation is below:

Write an animation that starts with a blank screen, and each half
second adds a small dot at a completely random location — both the x coordinate and the
y coordinate are chosen at random.

Hint: Since you need to keep all the previous dots and add one more, your “model”
should probably be an image rather than a number. How can you add a dot at a specified
location to an existing image?

Hint: It would be especially nice if you could start the animation with any image, of
any size or shape, and it would sprinkle dots at random all over that background, without
rewriting the handlers.

```
; Random dots
(define DOT
  (circle 4 "solid" "black"))

(define blank-screen
  (rectangle 200 200 "solid" "white"))
 
(define (next-dot x)
  (overlay/xy  x
               (min 200 (random 200)) (min 200 (random 200))
               (old-dot DOT)))

(define (old-dot x)
  (overlay/xy x
              (min 200 (random 200)) (min 200 (random 200))
              blank-screen))

(big-bang DOT
  (on-tick next-dot 1/2)
  (on-draw old-dot 200 200))
```

Comment: You're mixing the drawing with the computation of the next state.

Comment: `next-dot` is overlaying the old state in a random position on top of a blank screen with a random dot on it. Then the drawing overlays that image in a random position on a blank screen. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Side note: `(random 200)` is a number between 0 and 199. Limiting that to not be greater than 200 isn't very useful.

Comment: Okay I guess I got it to do what I needed it to by replacing old-dot with DOT. I also took out the min functions. Thanks for the tips, I don't know, but I feel like I had this yesterday and I wasn't satisfied with it because there was no feedback in the interactions window. @molbdnilo

Answer (score 1):

```
; Random dots
(define DOT
  (circle 4 "solid" "black"))

(define blank-screen
  (rectangle 200 200 "solid" "white"))
 
(define (next-dot x)
  (overlay/xy  x
                (random 200) (random 200)
               DOT))

(define (old-dot x)
  (overlay/xy x
              (random 200)  (random 200)
              blank-screen))

(big-bang DOT
  (on-tick next-dot 1/2)
  (on-draw old-dot 200 200))
```